# How to set framerate on uv4l with external usb camera

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, uv4l

I'm using external usb camera plugged to my raspberry 3b+. Since I'm not using raspicam, but the uvc driver I can't just set the framerate in config file like when you are using raspicam.

Is there a way to set it somwhere?

Answer (score 0):

`v4l2-ctl --set-parm=30`

seems like it should change the fps, you also need to specify the device with

`--device=`

With

`set-fmt-video=width=1024, height=640`

you can change the resolution. The changes however seem to not affect the video though. Fps seem to have no effect at all, so the mjpeg stream stutters alot, and WebRTC works great even though it's set to 5 for example. Changing the resolution only seems to upscale the image with 0 quality improvement.